# Error during SonarQube Scanner execution

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm running sonar-runner inside my project folder
I have put and configured the sonar-runner.properties in my project as well. But still the execution Sonar failed. Any idea as to what could be the problem ?

If project configuration file(sonar-project-properties) is being ignored then what is the workaround. Pl suggest asap.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error is telling you that the Scanner is not finding your project properties. That is likely because the default name of the file is not *sonar-runner.properties*, nor *sonar-project-properties*, but *sonar-project.properties*.